# Duda con consulta sql ventas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo que realizar una consulta que haga un dto del 30% en el precio de v del product con el que tenemos mas beneficio.

:

```
select 
    max(precioventa-precioproveedor) as beneficio
from 
    productos 
where 
    cantidadenstock > 0 
order by 
    beneficio desc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta como medio incompleta. Vos queres el update que tenes que hacer o que cosa?

Comment: no, ningun update. Solo es una consulta.

Comment: Y entonces que impide que hagas como hicimos ayer en otra pregunta tuya, envuelvas esto en otro select y multipliques beneficio por 0.7 (que es el 70% del valor?)

Comment: perdona, si que tengo que hacer el update :(

Comment: Ya me parecia muy raro que fuera solo el select... Entonces tu consulta es mucho mas compleja que este select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También puedes resolverlo con un JOIN sin que salte ese ERROR 1093, evitando así el procedimiento y la tabla temporal. Adjunto también el código para crear la tabla y hacer la prueba:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  precioventa float,
  precioproveedor float,
  cantidadenstock int,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_producto)
  );
INSERT INTO productos (precioventa, precioproveedor, cantidadenstock) VALUES
  ('12','10','5'),
  ('15','11','6'),
  ('25','20','8');

    UPDATE productos JOIN (
        SELECT id_producto,precioventa*.7 nuevoprecioventa
          FROM productos WHERE precioventa-precioproveedor=(
            SELECT MAX(precioventa-precioproveedor) FROM productos
          ) 
      ) c1 USING(id_producto)
      SET precioventa=nuevoprecioventa;
```

Comment: no tiene caso hacer los scripts de sql o de algún lenguaje de backend ejecutables aquí, pues la plataforma no los correrá, lo único que si puede ejecutar es código html, css y js

Comment: La verdad es que insertaba el código así porque con las {} y las etiquetas pre y code no me quedaba bien, sí que me chocaba un poco lo de ejecutar. ¿Cómo lo has insertado tú?

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo: marco el código y pulso Ctrl+k

Answer (score 1):

prueba agregandole la operacion precioventa-(precioventa*0.30) en tu consulta

ejemplo:

```
select 
    max(precioventa-precioproveedor) as beneficio
   ,precioventa-(precioventa*0.30) as descuento
from 
    productos 
where 
    cantidadenstock > 0 
group by precioventa,precioproveedor
order by 
    beneficio desc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: precioventa-(precioventa*0.30) = precioventa*0.70 ;)

Comment: Exactamente. @gbianchi

Comment: solo cambiarias max(precioventa) as precioventa,precioventa-(precioventa*0.30) as descuento. espero haber entendido

Answer (score 0):

Vayamos por partes.

precioventa-precioproveedor no asegura que un solo producto cumpla con esta condición. Mas bien puede haber multiples productos que cumplan con eso.

Entonces, el problema es que tu update, puede hacerlo sobre mas de una fila.

Sacando esa aclaracion de encima, primero obtenemos los codigoproducto que cumplen con esta condicion

```
select
    max(precioventa-precioproveedor) as beneficio
from 
    productos 
where 
    cantidadenstock > 0 
order by 
    beneficio desc 
limit 1;
```

Y usamos esta query para hacer la siguiente

```
select codigoproducto
from productos
where precioventa-precioproveedor = (
    select
        max(precioventa-precioproveedor) as beneficio
    from 
        productos 
    where 
        cantidadenstock > 0 
    order by 
        beneficio desc 
    limit 1;
)
```

Esa ultima query, devuelve todos los codigoproducto que cumplen con que el beneficio es el maximo.

Y ahora, aplicamos esa a un update

```
update productos set precioventa=precioventa*0.7 
where codigoproducto in (
    select codigoproducto
    from productos
    where precioventa-precioproveedor = (
        select
            max(precioventa-precioproveedor) as beneficio
        from 
            productos 
        where 
            cantidadenstock > 0 
        order by 
            beneficio desc 
        limit 1;
    ));
```

Comment: y como lo junto todo? Siento las preguntas, estoy empezando... y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'productos' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Exactamente.. You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery. lo dice el manual.. habria que generar ahora un procedimiento que lea los codigos a modificar, o mandarlos a una tabla temporal y de ahi actualizar. Ya sabes lo que tenes que hacer.

Comment: ¿Alguna ayuda ?

Comment: Eso. Averigua o como hacer una tabla temporal, o como hacer un procedimiento almacenado. Si esto es un ejercicio para la facultad (no lo parece) vas a poder aprender mucho. Si es tu trabajo, te recomendaria que hables con tu jefe o quien corresponda, le expliques el problema y aprendar como solucionan estas cosas donde trabajas.

Comment: Mi respuesta en este caso no sirve, porque lo que tenes que hacer es mas complejo.

Comment: Si esto es para hacer solo una vez, anota los codigos que tenes que actualizar y hacelo a mano!

Comment: Gracias, probaré a ver si me sale. Me has ayudado mucho, gracias.